# Change title "Additional Information" in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to change the title from the checkout page. But I just can change the label and the placeholder.

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Please type your PO number here and we will add it to the invoice.';
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = '';
     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the whole $fields array with a var_dump?

Comment: The array $fields include more than your information that you posted. Something like $fields['order']['order_comments']['title'] ?

Comment: I am using this doc but I think I cant do it by a hook https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands there is not hook to change the section title. But here's the hack if you are desperate enough to make the modification.

1. Locate your template folder
2. Create a folder named 'checkout'
3. Locate the file form-shipping.php in the Woocommerce plugin foler under templates/checkout/
4. Copy file in step 3 to the folder created in step 2
5. Now you have superpowers over the checkout form

Edit this line:

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/#

```
/**
 * Rename product data tabs
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );

function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'More Information' );            // Rename the description tab
    $tabs['reviews']['title'] = __( 'Ratings' );                         // Rename the reviews tab
    $tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Product Data' );     // Rename the additional information tab

    return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me:

```
function ajg_relabel_additional_information_tab(){
    return __( 'Specification', 'text-domain' );
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_additional_information_heading', 'ajg_relabel_additional_information_tab');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function th_wc_order_review_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

  if(is_checkout()){
    switch ($translated_text) {
      case 'Billing details' :
        $translated_text = __( 'Billing Info', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
      case 'Additional information':
        $translated_text = __('New Field Name', 'woocommerce');
        break;
     case 'Your order':
        $translated_text = __('My Order', 'woocommerce');
        break;
     case 'Product':
        $translated_text = __('Your Product', 'woocommerce');
        break;
    }
  }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'th_wc_order_review_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Woocommerce is not complety...

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/

You would check condition about the callback before add or replace some value in array, otherwise the tab will display with nothing inside.

```
/**
 * Filter product data tabs
 */
function filter_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    global $product;

    if ( isset($tabs['description']['callback']) ) {
        $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'More Information' );            // Rename the description tab
        $tabs['description']['priority'] = 5;           // Description
    }

    if ( isset($tabs['additional_information']['callback']) ) {
        $tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Product Data' );     // Rename the additional information tab
        $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 10;   // Additional information
    }

    if ( isset($tabs['reviews']['callback']) ) {
        $tabs['reviews']['title'] = __( 'Review' ) . ' (' . $product->get_review_count() . ') ';  // Rename the reviews tab
        $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 15;          // Reviews
    }

    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'filter_product_tabs', 98 );
```

Why ? because the developper Woocommerce will check the content of array in the tab template
(version 3.8.0) (WC

```
/**
 * Filter tabs and allow third parties to add their own.
 *
 * Each tab is an array containing title, callback and priority.
 *
 * @see woocommerce_default_product_tabs()
 */

$product_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );
    
    if ( ! empty( $product_tabs ) ) : 

....
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me if anyone is still after this change

```
//Shipping Weight custom tab name

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Additional Information' );  // Rename the Additional Information text
    return $tabs;

}
```

Comment: Note, this changes the Product tab title. Not the title of the textarea in Checkout.